# process() function in AuthenticationMiddleware.php takes sometimes too long

Tags: cakephp

Some pages need for a simple reload sometimes very long [between 4 and 45 seconds]. Unfortunately the delay isn't predictable. First I thought it's of course something I did wrong but after further investigations I found the delaying function.

---

It's in `vendor/cakephp/authentication/src/Middleware/AuthenticationMiddleware.php` the function `process()` running this code `$service->authenticate($request);`

```
public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler): ResponseInterface
{
    $service = $this->getAuthenticationService($request);

    try {
        $result = $service->authenticate($request);
        ^^^^^^^^ This call needs between 0.01 and 45 seconds
    } catch (AuthenticationRequiredException $e) {
        $body = new Stream('php://memory', 'rw');
```

---

These are some sample dumps from my execution time measurements:

A dump for `/api/shop` with a long execution time; scroll to the right to see the delta times between each time snapshot:

```
[2020-11-01T16:58:02+00:00] /api/shop/ - /vendor/cakephp/authentication/src/Middleware/AuthenticationMiddleware.php :0103 - Delta time:0.04342
[2020-11-01T16:58:14+00:00] /api/shop/ - /vendor/cakephp/authentication/src/Middleware/AuthenticationMiddleware.php :0107 - Delta time:11.81272
[2020-11-01T16:58:14+00:00] /api/shop/ - /vendor/cakephp/authentication/src/Middleware/AuthenticationMiddleware.php :0121 - Delta time:11.81295
```

Then, 17 seconds later [no change, just reloading the page] there is no delay:

```
[2020-11-01T16:58:31+00:00] /api/shop/ - /vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php                                :0071 - Delta time:0.03756
[2020-11-01T16:58:31+00:00] /api/shop/ - /vendor/cakephp/authentication/src/Middleware/AuthenticationMiddleware.php :0103 - Delta time:0.04211
[2020-11-01T16:58:31+00:00] /api/shop/ - /vendor/cakephp/authentication/src/Middleware/AuthenticationMiddleware.php :0107 - Delta time:0.04506
```

---

Any idea what the reason can be? It's very frustrating because it's totally unpredictable. As in the above real samples shown, within few seconds there is a huge delay and then it works for 3-4 times and then suddenly it delays again. As mentioned before, I am not doing anything; just reloading the page.

CakePHP 4.1.4

Comment: You'll have to dig a little deeper, there can be lots of processing behind that method. I'd hook up a debugger like Xdebug to generate proper profiling information that shows where exactly the time is spent. That being said, a shot in the dark, sporadic lags are often caused by schema cache (re)population (when the information schema is very cluttered). Locked sessions are also somewhat common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this case also under [CakePHP Github Issues](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/15114). The CakePHP member [othercorey](https://github.com/othercorey) gave me the advice to check `Authentication\Authenticator\SessionAuthenticator` and here I found the reason:

in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Session.php`
--> In the function `start()`
--> The call `if (!session_start()) {`

The full code:

```
    if (!session_start()) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Could not start the session');
    }
```

*Then the solution was quite simple*. I am using SSE and this was the reason for these unpredictable delays. After calling `session_write_close()` in the SSE function the page loads <2 seconds.

When I got some time I will check if sessions stored in the database may be another solution.